# Change Cache-Control nginx container on docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I installed docker on my linux and I installed nginx container like this:

```
docker pull nginx
docker run -it  -d -p 8081:80 --name web -v /mnt/Project/Flutter/Projects/app_web2/build/web:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Now I want to change `Cache-Control` on my nginx container. Because I write a pwa with flutter, Every time I changed my page, when I launch page I still see old version of page, Now I want to change nginx caching.
How can I change it's default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you can achieve this directly. There are two approach.

1. Run nginx container as you running as of now. Then perform following operation.

   ```
   docker exec -it <<containername>>
   ```

   go to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ( Edit this file)

   Note : This approach is problem as you have to do this every time.
2. Another approach is create custom image based on nginx.

   ```
   FROM nginx:latest      
   COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
   ```

This ./default.conf will reside in your directory and from where you execute following command.

```
   docker build . mynginx:latest
```

In this default.conf at your directory you can add custom header.

You can find sample over here : https://github.com/jp1482/mynginxwithcustomerheader